# issues sending requests to HTTPS kubernetes service

Tags: curl, https, kubernetes

I have a service on a host that I would like to send a curl request to.
The host is something like https://x-y-z.a.site.com. It is a service running on a kubernetes cluster in its own namespace.

Originally in my kubernetes service manifests I only had a port for http, but after I added a port for HTTPS

```
 - name: http
   port: 4444
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 4444
   nodePort: 30000
 - name: https
   port: 443
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 443
   nodePort: 30001
```

And in my deployment manifest I added

```
ports:
     - containerPort: 4444
       name: http
       protocol: TCP
     - containerPort: 443
       name: https
       protocol: TCP
```

When I send a curl request to the host without the port I get a `503 Service Unavailable` message. And when I curl with the NodePort:

```
curl -v https://x-y-z.a.site.com:30001
* Rebuilt URL to: https://x-y-z.a.site.com:30001/
*   Trying XX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
* Connected to x-y-z.a.site.com(XX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port 30989 (#0)
* Server aborted the SSL handshake
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

Any ideas on what I should look into/investigate further to get to the bottom of this issue? Thanks!

EDIT: I have tried sending a curl request with the `-k` flag as well but I still get the exact same result

Comment: looking like its stuck on ssl handshake. Did you deploy your SSL certificate?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, I ran this locally on my mac. How can I deploy on the SSL certificate on it?

Comment: not sure which application server your using. here is the sample for Nginx http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html setup.